# DbAdapter Plan Updates from Remote WLST connection

Tags: maven, jdbc, weblogic, jython, wlst

I am creating a Maven based remote deployment setup for weblogic and SOA.
I am using a python script which is executing remotely.
I have successfully managed to get it to create/update JDBC connections.
I now wish to update the DbAdapter deployment plan with the new JDBC connection. (Later I want to do this with the JMSAdapter as well)

I have found many links online which show how to do this via a local WLST connection.
https://redstack.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/automating-creation-of-jdbc-data-sources-and-dbadapter-plan-updates-and-redeployment/

I am getting an error with my remote script with the line:

```
plan = loadApplication(appPath, planPath)
```

The consensus online is that loadApplication will not work remotely.
A couple of different sources mention this but no source offers any workaround.

Is there a WLST based remote API I can use to add the configuration?
Can I download the plan.xml, alter it and re-upload it through WLST? (If so any tutorials?)
Is there an easier method that I am missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to use WLST redeploy instead of loadApplication? Redeploy should work for your scenario if you set planPath, upload='true' and remote='true' options.